# Is it possible to maintain a configuration of an arbitrary resource using pacemaker cluster

Tags: drbd, pacemaker, heartbeat, corosync

What I understood is that with resource agents (which are exactly same on all nodes), pacemaker can start/stop resource on any node. But can we also use it to sync a configuraton file in all nodes in the cluster.

For Example, I want my drbd.conf file to be same on all nodes and want to maintain it with pacemaker cluster. Is it possible and if it is, how?

So, in other words, I do not want the drbd itself to be maintained by pacemaker i.e., stop, start etc, only the configuration file. I am not saying it's an ideal usecase, just checking if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

To synchronize your configuration files, you can `csync2`, is not related to a pacemaker resource, pacemaker is not related to this kind of task.

example, you can include the following two lines in `/etc/csync2/csync2.cfg`:

```
include /etc/drbd.conf;
include /etc/drbd.d/*.res;
```

Now you can use `csync2 -xv`